# ESP8266 crashes when button is pressed

Tags: esp8266

I'm building a wireless QLab Go button based on an ESP8266-01. There is a web UI to connect to a wireless network and setup the IP address of the computer running QLab. When a button is pressed, the ESP is meant to send an OSC message to that computer.

In fact, this works. But only a few times. After, let's say pressing five times the button, the ESP becomes unresponsive. The blue LED flashes, but apparently the OSC message is not sent. Also, the webserver is unreachable.

Also remarkable: my FTDI232 doesn't always communicate with the serial monitor of the Arduino IDE... Any ideas on what might be wrong here?

```
#define FIRMWARE "v0.4.3"
#define VERBOSE
//#define LOAD_DEFAULTS

#define BUTTONPIN 2

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>
#include <OSCMessage.h>

#include "globals.h"


void setup() {
  EEPROM.begin(128);

  #ifdef VERBOSE
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("--------------------");
    Serial.println("QLab Spacebar Button");
    Serial.print("Firmware Version: ");
    Serial.println(FIRMWARE);
  #endif

  #ifdef LOAD_DEFAULTS
    #ifdef VERBOSE
      Serial.println("Load Default Settings:");
    #endif

    saveSettings();
    startHotSpot();
  #else
    // If we cant load settings from EEPROM, start the hotspot
    if (!loadSettings()) {
      startHotSpot();
    }
  #endif

  // Start hotspot if we're in standAlone mode otherwise we start the wifi
  if (standAlone == 1) {
    startHotSpot();
  } else {
    startWifi();
    allowHotSpot = 0; // Dont allow hotspot to run after this initial setup - must restart device to start it again
  }

  // Start WebServer
  startWebServer();

  // Start listening for UDP packets
  qUDP.begin(qlab_port);

  pinMode(BUTTONPIN, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(BUTTONPIN, spacebar, RISING);
}

void loop() {
  webServer.handleClient();
}

void spacebar() {
  #ifdef VERBOSE
    Serial.println("Received a click -- will send OSC message now!");
  #endif
  OSCMessage msg("/go");
  qUDP.beginPacket(qlab_address,qlab_port);
  msg.send(qUDP);
  qUDP.endPacket();
  msg.empty();
  delay(500); //Safety measure: you can't press the spacebar twice 
}
```

(Most of the other code is in other files, I think this is the only relevant part)

The wiring diagram for the ESP is as follows: (I don't know how to draw it so I'll just try to write it down...)

```
Gnd->Gnd
Tx -> Rx
Rx -> Tx
CH_PD -> 3.3v
Vcc -> 3.3v
GPIO2 -- 10k ohm resistor to 3.3v 
      \_ Gnd (this is meant to be a button: pulled to Gnd when pressed)
```

Comment: How are you powering the ESP8266-01 ? A USB connection may not be able to supply sufficient power in all situations although a large value capacitor connected across the supply close to the ESP will help

Comment: You should not do too much in an interrupt routine. Ideally you would just set a flag and then poll that flag in `loop()` and do all the work there.

Comment: @Bra1n I'm powering the FTDI with the USB port from my laptop indeed... Do you think this draws too much current? 
@Majenko I removed the interrupt and and put in the loop `if(BUTTONPIN == HIGH) { spacebar(); }` which seems to work better and consistently longer, although the webserver still isn't reachable all the time...

Comment: not sure if it applies to ESP's but with arduino, `delay` doesn't work inside an ISR, so that delay may be irrelevant anyway. But you're trying to do way too much inside the ISR as pointed out above

Comment: thanks for the comments -- moving the routine to the loop section seems to solve the problem. why is it that delays cause problems in an ISR?